# Execute javascript function with ID

Tags: javascript

I have a function to add or remove text

```
function additionalText()
```

When I use:

```
<a id="toggleButton" class="moreText" onClick"additionalText()" >See More</a>
```

The function executes correctly.

However, I want to have all my JavaScript in my .js file and use the ID id="toggleButton" to trigger the function. When I use:

```
onclick = function () {
additionalText();
}
```

I can click on any point of the page and the additional text is displayed. I just want it to execute when "See More" is clicked. I don't want to use jQuery, but I know it is something to do with an event listener and getElementById, but I am stumped -  Could someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Consider using jQuery instead if you are manipulating the `DOM`. It makes it MUCH easier.     EX: `$('#toggleButton').on('click', function(){` will do any magic you want to do, with hardly `22kb` of additional load time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1** You can easily do this by

```
document.getElementById('moreText').onclick = function () {
additionalText();
}
```

**2** If you want `onclick` through the HTML, you should put an equal sign, though:

```
onClick="additionalText()"
       ^Magic!
```

Simply `onclick` will assume you're adding the event to `window`.  Also, if you're using option #2, make sure your `additionalText()` function isn't defined *after* the window loads, or your HTML won't be able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
document.getElementById('toggleButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
   additionalText();
});
```

If you have to support old browsers too, do:

```
document.getElementById('toggleButton').onclick = function () {
   additionalText();
};
```

Cheers

Comment: This is a curiosity standpoint Edgar. Why wouldn't you use the shorter code that supports old browsers, instead of using the long-winded top approach with more characters?

Comment: @NicholasHazel Because the one that supports old browsers has an anti-pattern, it only allows to have 1 listener (and may overwrite a previous one). The first way uses the observer pattern so lets to attach more than 1 listener, that's why it's preferred if available.

Answer (score 1):

you added the function to the general onclick event.
This will execute the function by every click.

Try this

```
document.getElementById("toggleButton").onclick = additionalText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in JQuery I would use this stategy since it insures your element has loaded before you attempt to attach events to it.

```
$(function() { 
    $('#toggleButton').on('click', function() {
        additionalText();
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, we posted at the same time. Kudos sir :-)